# Using NSURLConnection WebService

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i get the follwing error below when i run the program given below

Error:
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x5948b80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x5948ac0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}

wat i need to do plz suggest me

thank u..

the code is given below

```
@implementation WebSampleViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@" http://www.googleapis.com/customsearch"]] retain];


    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [myConnection start];    

    [super viewDidLoad];
}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{

    [dataWebService setLength:0];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [dataWebService appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 

{

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);

    [responseString release];

    [dataWebService release];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"Error during connection: %@", [error description]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not `retain` **request** instance of type NSMutableURLRequest.

**You have an leading white space in your String URL.**

Use the below code .

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.googleapis.com/customsearch"]];
```

I think, you should check your URL , I give the same "Not Found" as on iPhone.

Comment: @Abhilash : Your url is wrong, check with other URL ...(http://www.google.co.in) ..

Comment: thank u but if i take out retain it comes error "expected identifier"

Comment: @Abhilash : Error or Warning ?

Comment: error...again i gave retain in code and changed url with www.google.co.in  it executed but blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the space at the beginning of your URL string.

Comment: @Abhilash: It does that in a browser too.  I suspect the URL is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove whitespace in your url